# How can this triangle figure be modeled/drawn with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, draw

How can the following image be drawn?

[image: Latex TikZ]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ti*k*Z has all sorts of shapes built in, including such triangles. Using these you can avoid having to specify explicit coordinates, and it is then much easier to make the shape a bit larger, to rotate it and so on.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
\path node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw,fill=gray!30,
inner sep=3em,rotate=180] (3gon) {} 
node[below] at (3gon.corner 1){{\large\bfseries Empathie}\\ Einf\"uhlung}
node[right] at (3gon.corner 2){{\large\bfseries Anerkennung}\\ bedingungsfreie\\ Wertsch\"atzung}
node[left] at (3gon.corner 3){{\large\bfseries Authentizit\"at}\\ Echtheit\\ Kongruenz};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be drawn with a single command in tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
\draw [fill=gray!20] (0,1)node[left]{Some\\text\\left} -- (2,1)node[right]{Some\\text\\right} -- (1,-.5)node[below]{Some\\text\\below} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]